# CNN for image classification with two outputs

Tags: python, classification, cnn, image

Is it possible to classify my images (cars parts) by the type of cars part(door, window ...) and also by the view of the image( front, back, right, left, top and bottom). My pictures are labelled like this: View_idPart, the view is a number from 2 to 7. I want to use a CNN model, but i don't know if this is possible? I hope that I will have some answers, I will be so grateful

Answer (score 0):

The view classification (front, back, ...) is the easier part as you have the correct labels in your dataset.

I would do it using transfer learning : pick a pre existing image classification model (such as VGG or Res-Net) and freeze it (`parameters.require_grad = false` in pytorch `layer.trainable = false` in keras), remove the last classification layers and replace them with your architecture with the correct number of outputs (6 classes in your case). Then train the network : it should only train the last classification part as we froze the convolutional part. And it should give good results depending on how complicated the initial CNN model is.

Transfer learning is only useful if you do not have much data in your dataset, i'd say it is not necessary to use a pre existing model if you have a lot of data (>100 000) in the dataset. If you have a big dataset, you can create your architecture from scratch and build your convolutional layers with an encoder-classifier architecture as represented below (blue + red are the convolutional layers and green is the classifier part) :

[image: Typical Encoder-Classifier Architecture, VGG 16]

I'm not sure to understand what you mean by *type of cars part(door, window ...)*, it seems to me you want to have another classifier that gives the car parts on the image, so the output should be something like : there is window, a door, but no trunk. This is also possible, but requires a dataset labeled with such information (which does not seem to be the case). Maybe you can find correlations between the view and the parts on the image and deduce it from there. Or if you have such a labeled dataset, just create another CNN and train it on this dataset (output may need to be slighty different if you want to predict different classes for one image).

Anyway, CNN is definitly the way to go for your problem as it is the most accurate models we have at the moment for image classification, and they are likely to perform way better than fully connected layers or other architectures.

Comment: what I want to say by the type of cars parts too is that the output should be something like: this picture is a door and the view is left for example. I have a big dataset with 400 parts of cars and another dataset with the same images but the structure is different, I made 6 classes (front, back...). You should also know that each image contains only one part of car. I don't know if it's possible to have one model to predict both of them. Or if it exists something like creating two models and then concatenate the two outputs but I don't know how. I hope you could help me, Thank you

Comment: Please, can you explain to me why we should not use transfer learning when we have big dataset? because I have more than 200 000 images. and what I wanted to use is the VGG model.

Comment: @LemaZaidiJust I would create 3 models :
1 - Convolutional pretrained model (part in blue and red)
2 - Part classifier
3 - View classifier
You send data through model 1 and then give the output of model 1 as input for your model 2 and 3 that are simple fully connected layers network (pick a simple architecture with few layers as your dataset is not consequent).

Comment: Transfer learning is usually the best way to go, what i will say might not be true, but is how i see it : Pre-trained models such as VGG are good at doing everything, but not perfect at recognizing one thing in particular (in your case car parts), so it may give better results to create a network that only knows how to do one thing (car parts), but does it perfectly. I see it as a tradeoff between how many things you can recognize and how good you are at recognizing them.

Comment: So if I use 3 models, I have to keep the two datasets ( one with 400 classes of parts and other with 6 classes of View), I'm right ? If I don't use transfer learning then I will keep the same idea but I will replace the first model by a new CNN model?

Comment: @LemaZaidi Correct, i advise starting using transfer learning and this 3 models architecture. If it doesn't give good enough accuracies, you  may try training your own CNN or VGG.
A tip to make transfer learning more efficient is to compute the features out of VGG for each image and create a new database made of pairs (features - class) instead of (image - class), so the network doesn't have to send the image through VGG each time. Made my training 5 times faster, which is handy if you want to try different architectures for classifiers. This only is helpful if VGG is frozen

Comment: Ok, thank you. Speaking of the new database, I don't really know how to do that, in fact i used ImageDataGenerator to have my trainig, testing and validation iterators, this is how i use my images. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: According to keras documentation, ImageDataGenerator is just something that rotates and introduce variability in your images, but a common way to save databases is to use folder for classes and then use Dataloaders such as keras `image_dataset_from_directory` function. Here is how my GetFeatures code was done (Pytorch again, you will have to convert it to TF if you want to use it) https://www.codepile.net/pile/4PD4R3Py (hope this link works)

Comment: But it allows us to use our data also, here is my code: train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes= CLASSES, batch_size=32). I used this because i have more than 200000 images and it doesn't take time at all. Is this not usefull ?

Comment: nvm, I didn't know about this method, which is pretty cool. Perfectly fine to use that

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a tutorial on how to code the classification algorithm check out this [article](https://databasecamp.de/en/use-case/cnn-in-tensorflow).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible, neural networks can have multiple output, you need to have a dataset fot this but you can do it yourserlf, using a pretrained model wouldn't require a big dataset.

Here you have a post doing this:
https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-multi-output-convolutional-neural-network-with-keras-ed24c7bc1178

Another post but with regression outputs:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-models-for-multi-output-regression/